# Geometry grid node - distorted textures

Tags: geometry-nodes

I wanted to create a procedural ice material using *Geometry Nodes*, but a problem arose: the snow texture is distorted, I wonder how I can resolve this.

You can see the problem in the attached screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: You're projecting a 2D texture down the Z of  3D geometry, Can you adjust 3D noise to work for you? If not, you may have to UV unwrap.

Comment: I'll let you know soon if 3D noise worked. How can I unwrap correctly a geometry node?

Comment: My bad, I thought you were displacing an externally created object. An option: instead of displacing by a noise-multiple of a fixed vector (your 1,1,0.4) you could displace by a noise-multiple of the Normal. Possibly, you would have more control with 2 displacements: One large scale for the general shape (the shelf) in 2D, and another finer one for the surface texture, by Normal.

Comment: Is there a way to displace the noise texture I made while preserving the original shape of the faces from the grid node? Like the "normal" displacement modifire do useing a height map, that would resolve my problem! I think...

Comment: 2 displacements should do that, if I understand you. Maybe share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I've uploaded it! The issue with displacement through shaders nodes is that the shaders only seem to work in Cycles and don't actually displace the mesh. This is a problem because I need the displaced mesh to distinguish between ice and snow based on the Z axis height so I can texture them separately with smooth transition.

Comment: Only thinking Bump, not Displacement, in the shader. That just bends the normals. Will have a look tomorrow.  (Late here) :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I changed the noise texture from 3D to 2D in the shader editor.
[image: Nodes]
[image: Result]